# Generating bootstrap grid with Foreach loop

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, razor, foreach

I'm really close to getting this accomplished. I'm trying to get 3 images across each row. The first row only has 1 image, though, then the rest have 3 across. I'm not sure why the first row has only 1 image. Here's my code:

```
        <div class="row">
        @{ var counter = 0; }

        @foreach (var x in portifolioImages)
        {
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="#"><img src="@x.UmbracoFile" alt="@x.imageTitle" style="margin:0 auto;" />
                    <p class="folioTitle">@x.imageClient <br /><span style="color:#00bfff; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; font-size:15px;">Learn More</span></p>
                </a>  
            </div>
            if (counter % 3 == 0)
            {
                @:</div><div class="row">
            counter = 0;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: remove this part             if (counter % 3 == 0)
            {
                @:</div><div class="row">
            counter = 0;
            }
            counter++; and then check

Comment: close but the first row had 2 images, then the rest had 3

Comment: if you want 3 images a row, why counter, boostrap grid will do it for you, `col-*-4` means `33.3% width` means each row divides equally into 3 so simple `<div class="row"> foreach { <div class="col-sm-4"> images </div> } endforeach</div>` should do the job

Comment: So despite it all being in one big row class i would still get a grid? Thanks i'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

Your counter starts at 0. The `if (counter % 3 == 0)` statement will be true when counter is 0, so your first row is only going to have 1 element. Start your counter at 1 instead of 0 and it should work.

Also, the reason it works fine after the first row is because you reset the counter to 0, but then immediately increment it to 1. So your first row is starting with counter at 0, but all the following rows start with counter at 1.

Comment: Should be noted that resetting the `counter` to 0 isn't necessary.

Comment: Tried this and the first row had 2 images, then the 2nd had just 1 images. The rest had 3 images.

Comment: @ChristopherNorthcutt And the only line you changed was `@{ var counter = 0; }` to `@{ var counter = 1; }`?

Comment: Yes but then i realized it was something in the CSS that was causing it to screw up again. I got it! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

should have just moved counter++ before the if statement.